# String printing

Tags: c, string

I'm  trying to have this string print out individual names. Instead of printing one name at a time, it prints all the names out. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_OF_NAMES 8
#define NAME_SIZE 3

void printNames(char names[][NAME_SIZE], int size);

int main()
{
   char nameList[NUM_OF_NAMES][NAME_SIZE] = {"Bob", 
                                             "Sue", 
                                             "Jak", 
                                             "Rod", 
                                             "Jon", 
                                             "Ash", 
                                             "Deb", 
                                             "Kay"};

   printf("\n\n\nLIST\n"); 
   printNames(nameList, NUM_OF_NAMES);
}

void printNames(char names[][NAME_SIZE], int size)
{
   for(int index = 0; index < size; index++) 
   {
      printf("%4s\n", names[index]);
   }
   return;
}
```

Comment: can you paste your exact output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in `char nameList[NUM_OF_NAMES][NAME_SIZE]` you have defined `NAME_SIZE` as 3 and you are storing exactly `3 char` into that, so there is no memory space kept for `'\0'` null terminator, as char buffer should be null terminated. To avoid this problem increase the `NAME_SIZE`. for e.g

```
#define NAME_SIZE 4
```

Secondly, from `main()` you are passing 2D array `nameList` you have to catch with pointer to an array like `char (*names)[NAME_SIZE]` not with 2D array as you did.

Here is the modified Code

```
#define NUM_OF_NAMES 8
#define NAME_SIZE 4
void printNames(char (*names)[NAME_SIZE], int size) { /*catch with pointer to an array of NAME_SIZE char */
        for(int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
                printf("%4s\n", names[index]);
        }
}
int main(void ){
        char nameList[NUM_OF_NAMES][NAME_SIZE] = {"Bob",
                "Sue",
                "Jak",
                "Rod",
                "Jon",
                "Ash",
                "Deb",
                "Kay"};

        printf("\n\n\nLIST\n");
        printNames(nameList, NUM_OF_NAMES);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason the program prints all names together is that the individual three-character names are not null-terminated. `printf` tries printing the first name, does not find null terminator, goes into the next name, then the next one, and so on. In the end, this is undefined behavior, because the eventual null termination of the whole arrays is not there.

This problem happens because `NAME_SIZE` is too small - it does not accommodate null terminator.

Fix this by changing `NAME_SIZE`:

```
#define NAME_SIZE 4
```

Enabling warnings and treating them as errors would help you avoid this problem in the future.